# Why does assigning a large number in one byte work in C?

Tags: c

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char));

*ptr = 100000;

printf("%d\n", *ptr); // 100000
```

Shouldn't that only allocate enough memory for a `char`, i.e. 1 byte? Therefore shouldn't the largest number be 255?

How does it still print `100000`?

#### Update

Thanks for the answers. If it overwrites the next bytes, how does C then know that this number is larger than one byte, and not just look in the first byte?

Comment: The short answer: Because C can't even spell "memory safety".

Comment: @R.. I hope the was the highlight of your day.

Comment: Regarding your updated question, it's largely meaningless because once you've written code that's invalid (i.e. invokes undefined behavior), anything can happen. What's happening on your implementation is that memory is a flat sequence of byte-size slots, and since you accessed the memory through an `int` pointer, the pointed-to byte and subsequent 3 bytes get accessed as an `int`. Sorry if I'm a bit impatient but every week we see 20+ "Why does this work?" questions about code with undefined behavior.

Comment: @R.. Well surely you must understand everyone has to start somewhere. IMO there is no place on Stack Overflow for people who downvote well intentioned questions, simply because *they* think it's stupid.

Comment: It's important to be aware that the value of the number you assigned is irrelevant. If you had written `*ptr = 1;`, you'd have the same problem -- because `1` is still of type `int`, and still occupies `sizeof (int)` bytes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because C has no range-checking of memory.  It allocates a byte, and then your assignment via the pointer overwrites it and the next three bytes. If you had allocated another bit of memory right after the first `malloc`, but before the assignment, you might have overwritten part of the heap (depending on how your malloc works).

This is why pointers can be very dangerous in C.

The `%d` in the format statement (plus the type of the variable) tells the compiler you are looking at an `int`, and accesses all four bytes.

Note that if you really had assigned the value to a char, e.g. `char *ptr; *ptr = 100000;`

then with some compilers (and assuming plain `char` is treated as signed but default) it would have printed out -96, not 255 (or 127).  This is because the compiler doesn't automatically limit the value to the highest value that can fit (127 in a signed char, 255 in an unsigned char), but instead it just overflows.  Most compilers will complain that you are trying to assign a constant value that overflows the variable.

The reason it is -96, is that 100000 % 256 is 160, but as a signed char it is output as -(256-160).

Comment: @alex: actually the info at the end is wrong; it's implementation-defined what happens when you assign a value that's not representable to a signed type, and it's implementation-defined whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned. If `unsigned char` had been used, the behavior would be well-defined.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: you're invoking undefined behaviour by writing to memory that doesn't belong to you, so you never know what you might get. It might just work, it might crash, or it might do any number of other things. In this case, you're putting an `int` at the position that `ptr` references, which writes the first byte of the `int` into the 1-byte allocated region, and smashes whatever lived in the following three bytes.

When you read the value back with the `%d` format specifier, `printf` reads `sizeof(int)` bytes from memory to print them as an `int`. If you want to output just the value of one byte, you need to do something like:

```
printf("%d\n", *(char*)ptr);
```

That is, tell the compiler that `ptr` refers to a `char`, then get that `char` value, which is promoted to an `int` in an argument list and subsequently output correctly by the `%d` specifier.

Answer (score 3):

This is 3 byte overflow. Overflow like this from stackoverflow logo, but on a heap not stack.

Comment: Who says it's 3 bytes? You're assuming `sizeof (int) == 4`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer would be: it's not guaranteed to work.

Basically, you are corrupting the memory around the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your updated question; C "sees" *ptr i.e. contents of ptr where ptr points at an integer. So it reads an integer from that ptr. It has already forgotten that you only allocated one character. The two parts (allocation and then access) aren't linked by anything you've expressed in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `malloc` will allocate memory with greater granularity than a single byte, so your request for a single byte will reserve a memory space rounded up to the nearest 8 bytes or something. You then write to this space, blithely going right past what you've reserved. Then you dereference the pointer, bringing back an `int`, and hand that to `printf` which happily prints it out.

As others have said, depending on this behavior is a bad, bad idea. Allocate exactly what you need and don't overrun your buffers.